# Php calculate hours elapsed from PM to AM

Tags: php, datetime, time

Time is confusing... How can one calculate the time elapsed from PM to AM in php?

For example `22:00:00 (10pm)` to `02:00:00 (02am)` should give `04 hours` elapsed. Instead my code returns `-08 hours`

```
function hours_elapsed() 
{           
    $timestart = strtotime("22:00:00");
    $timestop = strtotime("02:00:00"); 

    $time_diff = $timestop - $timestart; //time difference

    return gmdate("h", $total_hours);
}
```

It's clear that the code calculates in 24 hour format so of course it returns `-08` but how is it possible to get time elapsed without 24 hour constraint.. when it passes the midnight mark?

Comment: Your code doesn't know that $timestop is the next day so it thinks time elapsed is negative.

Comment: What is the source for the times? Do they start as xx:xx:xx strings?

Comment: @codewaggle i grab the times from the databse from column with field `TIME`, the format is always xx:xx:xx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-8` hours is `4` hours. Just add `12` if the number is negative:

```
$time_diff = $timestop - $timestart; //time difference

if ($time_diff < 0) {
  $time_diff += 12;
}
```

This won't help you, however, if your dates are more than one day apart. You need to specify the date as well (as in the day of the month) to tell PHP that those times are different.

Comment: Thanks! The hours never exceed 23 so I think it's ok. Easy solution :)

Comment: if i select time 01:0:00 pm to 01:16:00 pm then it shows 12:16:00 but the correct answer will be 00:16:00 how can i  solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly 22:00:00 is 24 hour clock, 02:00:00 could be either though couldn't it?

add the date as well, or test for the negtive and add 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution from me: add a day to the later date.

```
echo gmdate('h', strtotime('1970-00-01 02:00:00') - strtotime('1970-00-00 22:00:00'));
```

But Blender's answer seems to be easier. :)